# How to get IMEI (not UUID) of mobile handset using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, uuid, ngcordova, imei

I have a requirement to get the real device IMEI (64-bit number displayed when dialed '*#06#') using cordova.
ngCordova provides the UUID a hexstring. But UUID may change from user to user or after a factory reset as per the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579934/does-uuid-change-when-factory-reset-in-phonegap-android#).
Some google effort pulled me to a cordova plugin 'ngCordova-IMEI', but no luck with Android 6.0 (have not tried with other versions). Is there any way out?

Comment: Have you given <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [plugin](https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin) to do the job for you. But its android only solution as getting UUID is disallowed in iOS.

> This plugin allows you to retrieve most information about your Android devices that are available through Android's Telephony Manager and Account Manager classes from your PhoneGap application

Request you to check out the following SO posts for more info.

1) [Getting IMEI Number in cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987477/how-to-get-imei-number-in-cordova)

2) [Getting IMEI Number in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902222/how-to-get-device-imei-number-programmatically-using-xcode-to-phonegap)